# while loop not executing while evaluating 'string not in a string'

Tags: python

I made a function that would ask a player to enter a letter until the letter was X, x, O or o.
But, whenever i call the function , somehow the while loop evaluates to False and never starts executing. What might be the problem ? Thank you very much.

```
def getLetter():
    letter = ""
    while letter not in "XxOo":
        print("Would you like to be X or O ?")
        letter = input()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty string is member of all strings. Just try it in the Python prompt:

```
>>> "" in "lol"
True
```

You can initialise `letter` to some thing you know is not among the choices, for example `<not chosen yet>`, instead of the empty string.

Comment: Thank you , that solved my problem. I'll accept your answer as soon as the website allows me :D

Comment: You may also be looking for `raw_input()` and not `input()`.  "input([prompt]) - Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).".

Comment: `raw_input` has been renamed to `input` in python 3, which he's obviously using (note the parens after `print`)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the first line of the function to `letter = "David is cool"` and think carefully about what it means for the empty string to be contained in another string, e.g. `"" in "XxOo"`.

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense. If you consider `in` as a set operator you realize that the empty set is a subset of all other sets.

Comment: @Emil for strings, it's not a set operator, but instead does substring search. Otherwise `'foo' in 'foobar'` wouldn't work, as the elements of `foobar` are single-character strings.

Comment: Karl, in this context it would probably be better to consider the right-hand operand being "the set of all substrings in `foobar`", i.e., `{<empty string>, f, fo, foo, ..., o, oo, oob, ... ar, r}`